# Showing processing indicator in contact us form

Tags: asp.net, forms, redirect, web, contact-form

I have a contact us page in my website using ASP.NET
http://sosdeepcleaning.com/contactus.aspx

When clients fill up the form and click submit, it doesn't show any sign that the page is processing the form, so some of them click on the submit button twice.

How can I prevent them to click it twice? Dialog box? "waiting" bar? Alert?
Any easy solution I can add before Response.Redirect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the previous answer **disable** the button via **jQuery** upon first click, if the page is validated. Try the below snippet

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
       $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            // Assumes you have asp.net validation controls 
            // so you can check Page_IsValid
            if (Page_IsValid) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(this).attr("value", "Processing...");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common solution to the double submit problem is to gray out (disable) the submit button(s) and optionally show a progress throbber next to the submit button.

Using jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function()
{
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: Where should I put this statement?

Comment: It is a client side solution using JavaScript.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made an assumption when you mentioned progress bars and alert boxes that you are comfortable with scripting in JavaScript? Do you know how to attach an event for the form submit (using jQuery, for example)?